# How can I create a button to hide and show more tags per post?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tags

In my wordpress site, I have a page with multiple posts. Within these posts, there is an area for post tags. The number of tags vary and I have set a maximum number of tags to 5. Because some of these posts have more than 5 tags, is there a way to make a JS button that will show or hide the extra ones? For example, if the max number is 5, clicking SHOW will show more than 5, and clicking HIDE will bring the tags back to the original 5.

I have tried playing around with several pieces of code to put something together but my expertise is rather lacking.

The variable is intended to iterate over each post and search for all the tags (in this case - "a") for anchor links.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$('.show-all').click(function() {
       $('.tags-links').each(function() {
    var tags = $(this).find('a');
        console.log(tags.length);

  });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it really simple. I would hide the .tag-links with css `.tag-links:nth-child(n+5)` and if it has a a certain class, show the .tag-links.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqx97ebh/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show-all">show all</a>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #1</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #2</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #3</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #4</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #5</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #6</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #7</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #8</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #9</a>
  <a href="#" class="tag-links">tag #10</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tag-links:nth-child(n+6){
  display: none;
}
.show-tags .tag-links{
  display: inline;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('.show-all').on('click', function(e)
{
    $('.container').toggleClass('show-tags');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```